# JPEG device of ghostscript renders "Comment icon" from Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

When converting a PDF file to a sequence of JPG images, Ghostscript renders also the comment icons from Adobe Reader (see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvno3.png). Is there a way to somehow disable this behavior? Should I understand this as a bug or feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are annotations. From the Ghostscript documentation in gs/use.htm, section 5 "Using Ghostscript with PDF files":

> `-dShowAnnots=false`
>
> Don't enumerate annotations associated with the page objects through Annots attribute. Annotations are shown by default.

Comment: After adding this parameter, my Ghostscript 9.05 crashes after converting the last page of my PDF with the following error: "Error: /invalidrestore"
I'm executing the following: `gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dShowAnnots=false -sDEVICE=jpeg -dJPEGQ=97 -r120 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dMaxStripSize=8192 -dUseCIEColor -sOutputFile=img-%d.jpg file.pdf`

Comment: Well you could try running a more up to date version (current release is 9.14) if that still fails then I suggest you open a bug report and attach the relevant file. By the way, its a really bad idea to set -dUseCIEColor unless you know *exactly* why you are doing it.

Comment: OK, I will try a newer version. I'm using this in a web application where users can upload their PDF files for printing. Ghostscript converts the PDF to JPEG images and these images are displayed in the browser as previews. The -dUseCIEColor is there to preserve the same colors in the previews as the user had in the original PDF. So is it still a bad idea, or it is OK now? BTW why is it a bad idea anyway? Thanks.

Comment: That's not what UseCIEColor does. It converts every incoming colour into  a CIEBased colour space, so the one thing it *won't* do is 'preserve the same colors in the preview'. Its still a bad idea. The reason its a bad idea is because of what it does, its a crude and not very effective colour management technique. It can be made to work *IF* you know exactly what you are doing with it, which almost nobody does.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! So what I want to achieve is to keep the ICC profiles from the PDF in the JPG preview. Is that possible?

Comment: As I understand it, a JPEG can only have one ICC profile (ie the whole image is described in a single ICC colour space) A PDF by contrast can have many, so this isn't really a viable goal. If you have certain kinds of PDF (eg PDX/X-3) then its possible to arrange for the PDF/X-3 profile to be emitted in a TIFF, I'm not certain it can be included in a JPEG. You can try this by specifying -dUsePDFX3Profile but only, of course, if your incoming files are PDF/X-3

Comment: The problem is, that the PDF is uploaded by the user, so I cannot predict what type of PDF will be uploaded. I just want to give him the most exact preview as possible. So regarding to your answer it seems to be not really solvable.

Comment: Don't mess with the colour would be my advice. There are too many variables involved, most of them unknown for you to 'solve' this, colour management only works properly in a colour managed workflow, which you don't have. Just render them to RGB and it'll be close enough for most people.